# Python Kivy: How to globally store the value of a text input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I've tried literally everything, but nothing seems to work. I want to use the textinput variable 'self.email_entered.text' in the other class (another screen) - InfoPage(). How should I solve this problem???

```
email_id_global = " "

class ConnectPage(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ConnectPage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.enter_email_id = Label(text="Email:”)
        self.add_widget(self.enter_email_id)
        self.email_entered = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.email_entered)
        self.login_acc = Button(text="Login")
        self.add_widget(self.login_acc)
        self.login_acc.bind(on_press=self.login_btn)

    def login_btn(self, _):
        —-some code —-
    def get_email(self):
        global email_id_global
        email_id_global = self.email_entered.text


class InfoPage(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(InfoPage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print(email_id_global)  #output = " "
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. No way to tell for sure what is happening without more information.

Comment: http://inclem.net/2019/06/20/kivy/widget_interactions_between_python_and_kv/

Comment: Done, can you check it now?